# Is there a method for decomposing a complex function into the sum of its real and imaginary part?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

I know that for every function $f:X \to \mathbb{C}$ there exists a pair of functions $u, v:X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = u(x) + iv(x)$. This is of course trivial because you can just say $u(x) = \Re (f(x))$ and $v(x) = \Im(f(x))$.

However my question would be if there exists an algorithm or method to compute more meaningful functions for $u$ and $v$. By more meaningful I mean that the result will be more efficient than just calculating $f$ twice and then discarding half of the results.

An example of this would be decomposing $$f(z) = z^2$$ into $$u(z) = x^2 - y^2 \\v(z) = 2xy$$, where $x = \Re(z)$ and $y = \Im(z)$; [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Simple_example).

I am especially interested in functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by calculating $f$ twice?

Comment: @mrsamy I mean that if I were to compute the values of $\Re(f(z))$ and $\Im(f(z))$ seperately I would calculate the entire function twice insted of just calculating both parts once. (When I use $u(z)=\Re(f(z))$ and $v(z)=\Im(f(z))$)

Comment: You don't have to calculate $f(z)$ twice. You just calculate it once. Then you take the result and apply it twice by plugging the result into the two expressions $\Re(f(z))$ and $\Im(f(z))$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Not in the case where I want to solve $\Re(f(z)) = 0$ and then calculate $\Im(f(z))$, where $z$ is said solution. Maybe there also is a completely different way to accomplish this which I have entirely overlooked.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic, then knowing either $u(x,y)$ or $v(x,y)$, you can compute the other (up to a constant).

Comment: @mjw How would you do that?

Comment: @Leander, using the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \Rightarrow v=\int \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, dy + \phi(x)$, *etc.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Re{f}= \frac{f+\overline{f}}{2}$ and you can express the imaginary part in a similar fashion.